# What is the name of this cable that goes into a modem?

Tags: internet, modem, cable

I have bought cable internet from teksavvy and the modem arrived however the cable that comes out of the wall and goes into the modem where it's labelled "Cable", is very short.

What's the name of this cable? But most importantly can I buy one that can extend this cable so I can bring the modem closer to my PC?

If so, please advise where and which cable I should be looking for? Would canadian tire carry this item for instance?

[image: picture]

Comment: Pictures? Pin count? Anything?

Comment: I couldnt find a picture of it because typing modem cable only seem to show ethernet cables. This doesnt have pins but you secure the cable onto the modem by rotating the end attachment, so it has the ridges(?), not pins.

Comment: Make and Model of modem??

Comment: It says it's thompson. Also took a picture with ipod but bad lighting because the cable is in an awkward position: http://i.imgur.com/aB9OT.jpg

Comment: Modem is thomson dcm475.

Comment: Btw I am posting this from ipod, that's slow to make changes to the question.

Comment: Get some better lighting on it so we can see in the end of it. You say there's no center pin/wire, a blip of light seems to make it have one.

Comment: As Fiasco said, please retake the picture with better lighting. I tried to enhance it a bit, but there's only so much you can do...

Comment: lol guys I only have ipod to take pics and there is no light in that room and the cable barely reaches the window and it's already dark outside.

Comment: New pic lighted with cell phone, actually it was the male version my bad: http://i.imgur.com/VSPGd.jpg

Comment: Yep, that was what I was expecting to see. Any place that services cable tv will have these pre-made up (cable tv patch cable). In the states Radio Shack tends to be the place to go, though Walmarts carry them. Your cable guy just pulled some coax off a reel and crimped the ends on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would guess that it is most likely an F Connector: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector
[image]

Yes Canadian Tire would most likely carry an F Connector. If not you can easily purchase these connectors (or already crimped cables) online (just search google for it).

Comment: Thanks mine is that except it doesnt have that bronze colored pin in the middle. Does it matter?

Comment: You may be describing the female version of this. Most cable connectors are described as male or female for fairly obvious reasons.
Is this more what you are talking about? http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/241830874/BNC_Connector_Female_to_F_Connector/showimage.html

Comment: Thanks gotcha I will get the female version then. The input also is solid and has no hole, anyway. Other than this there would be no other f connector right? i.e. bigger radius connection, etc? Lastly would extending this have any impact on the speed of the connection?

Comment: There is no other version of this connector in widespread use, no. Extending the cable should have no noticeable effect on the speed of the connection. (As long as you use an appropriate shielded cable). See the discussion here: http://www.dslreports.com/faq/5420

Answer (score 12):

You have cable internet and this is either **75 Ohm** `rg-59` or `rg-6` quad shield coaxial with a compression F-connector.

[image: You install them with this after using a proper stripper] [image: They look like this]

Comment: Why not 75 Ohm RG-59 or RG-6, as used by cableTV companies that also provide ISP?  Not likely that she has thin Ethernet.

Comment: @sawdust. Yep, the other left hand. I work with avionics so 50 Ohm cable comes to mind first. You are absolutely correct. 75 Ohm and rg-59 or rg-6. At least I had the quad shield right...

Comment: Specs for that Modem: WAN throughput: 340 Mbps
WAN throughput upstream: 131 Mbps WAN ports: 1 WAN port(s) type: Coax F-connector LAN ports: 1 LAN ports type: 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet (RJ-45)

Comment: I vote that the center wire has broken off or has pulled back into the connector if you don't see one.

Answer (score 6):

Cable modems are commonly connected on the server side with a 75 Ohm RG-6 coaxial cable , terminated with a "F" connecter.  The "bronze" thing is the actual copper center wire (18 gauge) of the coax cable.

The longer cable you want can most easily be found in the TV antenna section of a store.  Lengths of 3', 6', 25' and much longer RG-6 coax cable should be available.  You would be better off using just one long cable.  Do not extend the old by getting a joiner & new cable, or an extension cable with a female end (instead of both ends male).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Keep the runs intact with no extra connections. This is a DOCSIS 3.0 modem that would appreciate as clean a signal as it can get.

Comment: Thanks guys but how can I use a longer one? The end of the cable is buried inside the wall. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, I assumed there was a wall plate that had an exposed female "F" connector.  Then you will need to use a joiner or coupler (both ends are female "F" connectors, http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/27-5661) and the new cable.  This ends up being the same number of connections as having a wall plate.  Look for this stuff at an electronics, hardware or TV store, not at a computer store.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an [F connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector):

[image]